# Перебор массива, новый массив элементов

Tags: javascript

```js
const array = [
  { a: 10, social: "Twitter" },
  { b: 20, social: "Facebook" },
  { c: 30, social: "Instagram" },
];
   
let a = array.map(item => item.social[0]).join('');
console.log(a);
```

Не получается вывести массив с последними буквами (rkm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  { a: 10, social: "Twitter" },
  { b: 20, social: "Facebook" },
  { c: 30, social: "Instagram" },
];

let a = array.map(item => item.social[item.social.length - 1]).join('');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Жаль на javascript.learn такой способ не описывается :)

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, лучше подходит не метод map, а метод reduce, потому что он возвращает некий результат, а не измененный массив.

```js
const array = [{
    a: 10,
    social: "Twitter"
  },
  {
    b: 20,
    social: "Facebook"
  },
  {
    c: 30,
    social: "Instagram"
  },
];

let a = array.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.social[item.social.length - 1],
  '');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как понять где нужен метод map, а где reduce?

Comment: map нужен для того, чтобы преобразовать массив в другой массив. Например умножить все числа в массиве на 2. А метод reduce нужен, если нужно получить какой-то объект или значение из всех элементов. Например, получить сумму всех элементов массива.